# HttPost some values are not updating in the db

Tags: c#, http, post, precision

By posting a request to my database, I only get string values .For some reason, the floating values don't get to the DB.

Model

```
  public DateTime ? Date {get;set; }

  public double latitud { get; set; }

  public double longitud { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  Model Request = Model;
```

```
     Request.latitud=location.Latitude;
     Request.longitud=location.Longitude;
     Request.Date=DateTime.Now;
     Request.Name=Name;
```

Service:

```
    public async Task<string> Post(Model Request)
    {
     var response = new ServiceResponse<string>();
      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
           InitClient(httpClient);

          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
               "Content-Type", "application/json");

           var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(API_URL,
                new 
            StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request),
                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            Debug.WriteLine("post results : " + result.Content);

           }

        }
       return response;
      }
```

Date, Name is successfully posted anytime I called the service, 
 However, none of the doubles values does. NOTE- I am 100% sure that all the values are been sent in the object Request.

Comment: When setting the default headers you're setting the Content-Type header to `application/json-patch+json` but your StringContent says its Content-Type is `application/json`. This may not be the problem but I'll point it out anyways. Also, how does the endpoint look like? The problem may not be on the sender-side

Comment: Good catch! on the server side is expecting double`s as well.

Comment: So, what data are you actually sending? json-patch or json? Also, if you have access to the code on the server-side please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56114138/edit) your post and add the method your calling